# spark-1.4 with zeppelin installation

Tags: installation, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

After successfully install spark 1.4, I tried to install Apache Zeppelin for note-book like utility.

From some other online resources, I download and unzip the zeppelin source and started to compile with Maven via

```
$ mvn clean install -Pspark-1.4 -DskipTests
```

(spark home exported in the environment)

I got nice INFO output for about 4 minutes but things stopped with error when:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
```

and here is the error message:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.nflabs.zeppelin:zeppelin:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:7 from/to nflabs public repository (https://raw.github.com/NFLabs/mvn-repo/master/releases): Connect to raw.github.com:443 [raw.github.com/199.27.76.133] failed: Connection timed out and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 26, column 10
```

Is there something I forgot or should modify beforehand?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Try with sudo command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it cannot connect to Connect to raw.github.com:443

I can think of two options:

- you have a local maven repo that you can use as an artifact proxy (e.g. Nexus) and you will have to setup a mirror in ~/.m2/settings.xml
- You might beed to configure access through proxy in ~/.m2/settings.xml, here is how:

  https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html